# SQLite & PHP prepared statements

Tags: php, python, sqlite

I've been working on prepared statements for a while now and keep running into errors like:

- Warning: SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: class
- Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

I'm looking for some help.

I currently have a form that takes the users name and pet as shown beneath

```
    <form method="post" action="cgi-bin/post-data.php">
        name:<input type="text" name="name">
        pet:<input type="text" name="pet">
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
        <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
    </form>
```

This information gets posted to `post-data.php`. Inside `post-data.php` I intend on taking these values and selecting other information from a table based on both the *name* and *pet*. The contents of the php file are shown beneath.

post-data.php

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('club.db');
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM class WHERE name = ? AND pet = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['pet']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

I then intend on taking the values that are returned from this, and using them to display them on python file that also prints out a webpage.

Within the python file, I want to take the contents and just print them to the screen so I know I'm along the right lines.

I am using this:

tester-website.py

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("php cgi-bin/post-data.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

Thanks for any assistance. The aim is to secure my website so that the values are hidden.

If any more information is required, do not hesitate to ask.

Thank you for your patience, this is my journey to keeping my brain young.

Edgar

Comment: *no such table: italy*, you're using `class` as table name, the other error will cascade..but considering you have not even defined $stmt.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry, changed the error to correspond with the question.

Comment: also your referencing the file directly in the form but using `#!/usr/local/bin/php`, that won't work if your using browser and posting a form over HTTP, then the file would be run through a webserver -> php engine. tester-website.py is just running the file its not going to run a webserver

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks, I was unaware of this. I thought you included this in all php files.

Comment: Where does your `$stmt` variable come from?

Comment: @Shawn I'm not entirely sure, I think it's supposed to derive from this line: `$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM class WHERE name = ? AND pet = ?");` but my version is incorrect.